# Not choosing correct table cell on table click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to build a table where, on click, an X will appear on the cell that was clicked. Here is my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/67cmjL57/).
Unfortunately, the program always chooses the first cell in my table. What am I doing wrong here?

jQuery:

```
function addltr ()
{
    var data = "#" + $('#board td').attr('id');
    alert (data);
    $(data).html("X");           
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#board td").click(function() {
        addltr();
    });
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have updated your jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/67cmjL57/1/

Simply just pass the element via

```
Event.target.id
```

Working code:

```
  function addltr (name){
   var data = "#" + name;
   alert (data);
   $(data).html("X");           
  }

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#board").click(function(event) {
        addltr(event.target.id);
    });
});
```

Comment: @HarshulSahni Glad to hear that :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way you could do it: I added a class each time a cell was clicked, and inserted the HTML alittle differently. Then i check that the `td` doesn't have the class `clicked` to ensure that only 1 `X` is created for each `td`.

Updated [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/egesku79/)

Comment: Thanks dude, I just turned it into a function for a little more organization, but it was more than I needed. Once again, thanks a lot.